# Error control while importing a CSV file in postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a large CSV table I need to import into PostgreSQL. There is an alphanumeric column that I believe it could be VARCHAR(100). If I try to import the CSV file I want to be warned if during the process a string with length > 100 failed to be imported because of its length. How can I be sure that this error will be reported by PostgreSQL during the importing process? I will also need for the whole process to be halted so I can adjust the data type of the mentioned column to support that problematic row. I am using a cmd like:

```
copy myTable from 'myTable.csv' with delimiter E'\t' null as '' CSV HEADER;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with a file constructed to violate these limits?

Comment: No, but I want to be sure that this is always enabled by default

Comment: Postgres doesn't silently truncate, so you should get some kind of error. I'd suggest testing it to see *exactly* what error you get.

Comment: Great news, Thx